# Improve formatting of headlines

Tags: bug, design

The in-text headlines created by `#`, `##`, `###`, `<h4>` and `<h5>` (and turned into `h1`, `h2` and `h3` HTML tags or kept as is) are too large in the current design and are followed by too much vertical space. The first order one seems to be OK, but the second and third order headlines have a vertical space equal to about one empty line and should be reduced in size as well.

I find especially the third level headline very useful for less important headlines, even if there is no upper headline. This is probably the only case most people use headlines here anyway. In the current form it is not really useful for this because it stands out too much. I actually started to use manual bold formatting with a manual line break instead. Making the third order headline only marginally larger than the usual text, but bold with only a little bottom margin would look much better in my opinion.

`<h4>` and `<h5>` look exactly the same and they are simply a bit larger than paragraph text.

Here an example text to see the current formatting of headlines:

---

## First order

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

### Second order

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

#### Third order

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

Heading four

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

Heading five

text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text

---

Comment: Thanks, @Sklivvz, I didn't know about the possibility to add `<h4>` and `<h5>` manually.

Comment: Reading this on a mobile device: it's all backwards, with larger 3rd level than 1st level. Will raise another ticket.