# Links are styled identically to surrounding text (many instances)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

This issue was mentioned in the [Election Results](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/election-results) meta post, but I keep running into it so I think it deserves a post of its own.

It seems to be a widespread bug in the new design that links are styled identically to the surrounding text, often even when the user hovers over the link (the only thing changing being the mouse pointer). The most recent one I found was on returning to the main Skeptics site today, on getting the "You've been logged in, click here to continue" banner message, where "click here" is unstyled, even on hover. It could be bold, underlined, or a different colour, but it is none of those, even when hovering over the link. The list of places I think this bug exists (please add to this if you encounter others):

- In the "Welcome back, you've been logged in, click here to reload" banner, "click here" is unstyled, even on hover
- The link to your user profile as well as "review", "chat", "meta"/"main", "about" and "faq" on the top bar. Other sites use underline-on-hover here.
- In the [meta election post](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/election/1), where the link to the voting data is unstyled
- While writing this meta post, the "Similar Questions" look like a simple bullet-point list, but are actually links (perhaps the trailing chevrons used elsewhere would be appropriate, but they need something, even an on-hover styling)
- In the newsletter promotion sidebar on main, "see an example newsletter" is unstyled, even on hover (trailing chevrons appropriate?)
- On main in the community bulletin sidebar ([as mentioned in another meta post](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1771/links-in-community-bulletin-should-be-easily-identifiable))- these links I'd be happy to leave unstyled but I think should change on hover (even just to be underlined)
- On main, when viewing a question, the "linked" and "related questions" sidebars have unstyled links (on stack overflow these are blue text and also underlined-on-hover)
- When viewing a question, the question title is a self-referential link, which is underlined on hover on other sites but unstyled here
- When viewing the FAQ, the links in the sidebar are unstyled, even on hover

Is it possible to alter the stylesheet so that links are at least underlined or underlined-on-hover by default, and any special styling can override that as required?

More generally, why was black text without any underlining or hinting chosen? Could we not use a different colour to denote links, like on StackOverflow or any of the other sites?

Comment: Thank you for putting this together. I want to also add [link on election page](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/link-to-submit-moderation-election-nomination-is-invisible) and also when you visit a closed question it says "question closed by user1, user2, user3..." those user names are hidden links as well.

Comment: Found another. In user profile tab=activity some of my comments contain links that are not stylized.

Comment: The [“start a bounty” link](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1819/82) also  suffers from this.

Answer (score 2):

Just my 5 cents: yup, this is definitely a bug. The new design in fact contains [a](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1670/82) [few](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1794/82) [more](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1771/82) [glitches](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1719/82).