# Not enough contrast on Skeptics logo in some places

Tags: bug, design

Sometimes when our logo shows up some places without enough contrast.

[image]

Example 1 - from [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/skeptics/queries).

[image]

Example 2 - from chat.

While I'm talking about our logo, this is how our logo shows up [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/), I think it looks pretty terrible because it's off center.
[image]

Comment: An off-center yellow-on-dark logo is also used in chat for the rooms and transcript pages.