# How to start a new bounty on a question on which a bounty was already offered?

Tags: discussion

[Does plucking the feathers from live and conscious birds cause them pain?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/7856/does-plucking-the-feathers-from-live-and-conscious-birds-cause-them-pain)

I don't see any start bounty link on this question.
When I have 100 points, I would like to restart a bounty there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can’t see the link because you currently haven’t got enough reputation to start a bounty. However, the link is there, below the comments:

[image: screenshot of bounty link]

Unfortunately, the link isn’t very visible as such. This is a [design bug](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1787/82) that needs to be addressed.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the reason. It makes sense. :) currently I don't even have the reputation to upvote anything on the main site. :D